# Можно ли как-то передать данные в subprocess?

Tags: python, git

При запуске процесса выскакивает окно для ввода данных пользователя(логин, пароль), можно как-то передать в процесс данные чтобы он их использовал?

```
p = subprocess.run("git clone " + repository_url + " " + file_path, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [переменной окружения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment) [GIT_ASKPASS](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) можно указать программу, которая вернет в stdout пароль. Попробуйте указать там "echo password"

Answer (score 0):

имхо, проще клонироваться по ключу.

```
ssh-agent $(ssh-add /somewhere/yourkey; git clone git@github.com:user/project.git)
```

Comment: вся проблема в том, что в консоле не должен светиться логин и пароль

Comment: при работе с ключом, он не спросит даже логина и пароля.

Comment: а по https никак нельзя сделать?

Comment: можете хранить логин и пароль в файле .git-config https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329621/storing-git-config-as-part-of-the-repository

Comment: так или иначе вводить логин и пароль в окно - не самая лучшая идея. поскольку будете работать с GUI под определенную операционную систему. если важно не шарить логин и пароль, то создавайте юзеров и давайте права на чтение, или делайте публичным репозиторий.

Comment: я пишу бекап скрипт, который клонит закрытую локальную репу. И надо чтобы все было автоматически. Видимо единственный вариант это создать .gitconfig файл и использовать метод библиотеки gitpython git.GitConfigParser

Comment: я пытался сделать  
p = subprocess.Popen("git clone *******", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
p.stdin.write('username\n')
p.stdin.write("12345678\n")
но он просит поток байтов а не строку

Comment: если так, почему бы просто не использовать git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git ? Если перед командой поставить пробел (на линуксе), то в историю не будет записано (вроде так).